# How to Parse Referral Links Using SQL

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, utm, dbvisualizer

Hello StackOverflow world,

I have a datasource that stores all of my website session data and I am hoping to analyze the referral URLS and group them into five categories: **Home Site** (www.mywebsite.com), **Sub Site** (www.mywebsite.com/employees), **Outside Traffic** ,**Google**, **Yahoo**, **Bing**, **Facebook**, **Linkedin**, and **Youtube**.

In order to do this, I must parse the referral URLs. I have it partially figured out, but my current query mis-classifies URLS from outside websites that include our domain in their URL. When my query runs it will not group these URLs as **Outside Traffic** but create its own grouping as the name of the referral url.

For example, using this URL you can see how the name of my site is embedded in their URL:

```
https://www.helpthepeople.com/redirect.action?link=https%3A%2F%2F**www.mywebsite.com**%2Femployers%2Fblog%2Fwhat-to-do-when-asking-for-help%2F&encoded=lFAJCUeGqgrDkdlYfDwwbEfCqGlV
```

I get the following output:

```
www.helpthepeople.com
```

Desired output:

```
Outside Traffic
```

For the most part my query is working, but I am only having issues when the example above is present. Anyone know a better way to write this? My query is below:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%mywebsite.com%' 
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%mywebsite.com/employees%' 
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'.com/',2),'/',1)
         WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%google%' 
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%yahoo%' 
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%bing%' 
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%facebook%'
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%linkedin%'
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
        WHEN referrer_page LIKE '%youtube%'
            THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)  
        ELSE 'outside_referral_traffic' 
    END AS url_grouping,
    referrer_page,
    session_date,
    channel,
    medium,
    web_source,
    campaign_name,
    id, 
    COUNT (DISTINCT id) AS number_of_sessions
FROM biz_sessions
WHERE session_date >= '2019-07-01' AND session_date <= '2019-07-31'
GROUP BY 
    referrer_page,
    session_date,
    channel,
    medium,
    web_source,
    campaign_name,
    id
```

Comment: your OP does not match your desired output after updating it

Answer (score 0):

in `SQL SERVER` using `replace`,`charindex` and `left`

```
declare @string varchar(800) = 'https://www.helpthepeople.com/redirect.action?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Femployers%2Fblog%2Fwhat-to-do-when-asking-for-help%2F&encoded=lFAJCUeGqgrDkdlYfDwwbEfCqGlV'

select left(replace(replace(@string,'https://www.helpthepeople.com/redirect.action?link=',''),'https%3A%2F%2F',''),charindex('%2F',replace(replace(@string,'https://www.helpthepeople.com/redirect.action?link=',''),'https%3A%2F%2F',''))-1)
```

you can just easily translate this to `MySQL`

Comment: Would I need to declare this for every single URL or string that is considered outside traffic? I have hundreds of URLs referring traffic to the site.

Comment: you will need to show your full data as this solution was for the older version of your OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement is exiting at the first option because it satisfies the LIKE condition of your website name being in the entire URL. I would just split the referral URL by question mark to get rid of all parameters that might possibly include your website URL and a bunch of other things. The query might even work faster.

```
CASE 
    WHEN SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'?',1) LIKE '%mywebsite.com%' 
    THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(referrer_page,'//',2),'/',1)
    ...
END
```